# I am trying to use SendInput, but I can't figure it out

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winable.h>

int main()
{
    INPUT input;
    int a;
    while (1) {
        while (GetAsyncKeyState(0x5A)) {
            input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
            input.ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(0x01, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
            input.ki.time = 0;
            input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
            input.ki.wVk = 0x01;
            input.ki.dwFlags = 0;

            SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> `MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC` was not declared in this scope

I retyped it to see if my IDE(codeblocks) popped up any pedications in the drop down menu and it didn't show anything, so I assume it doesn't exist. I thought it did because I saw it on a piece of example program on some site (don't remember which, but it's not really necessary).

What am I supposed to put on that `wScan` line?

Comment: Why are you using `input.ki` for `INPUT_MOUSE`? You should be using `input.mi` instead. [Read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270.aspx). `MOUSEINPUT` does not have a `wScan` field, because mouse input does not use scan codes, only keyboard input does.

Comment: Completely unclear what you're asking. The title suggests some issue with `SendInput`, yet the question revolves around `MapVirtualKey`. Unlikely to be helpful to anyone. Voting to close.

Comment: `MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC` is defined in the same `winuser.h` header file that `MapVirtualKey/Ex()` is defined in. So you should not be getting a "not declared in this scope" error (unless someone intentionally used `#undef MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC` before you call `MapVirtualKey()`, but that is not the case in your provided example).

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you send a mouse click using Send Input:

```
enum sendInputs { MOUSE_DOWN, MOUSE_UP, NUM_INPUTS };
INPUT inputs[NUM_INPUTS];
//left down
inputs[MOUSE_DOWN].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
inputs[MOUSE_DOWN].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;

//left up
inputs[MOUSE_UP].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
inputs[MOUSE_UP].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
SendInput(NUM_INPUTS, &inputs, sizeof(inputs));
```

And you only need the `#include "Windows.h"` header, nothing else besides iostream.

Comment: It's pretty much always a mistake to pass 1 as the first parameter to SendInput. Read the documentation to understand why.

Comment: That, and arbitrary `Sleep` invocations are a strong indication, that you do not understand `SendInput` (or input in general). **-1**

Comment: Okay, thank you for your feedback. I will use it to improve.

Comment: I edited the code to conform to the documentation, but the Sleep function was placed there purposefully to simulate a mouse click.